# Status of Download - Chef Recipe

Tags: java, ubuntu, chef-infra, recipe, cookbook

I have a simple recipe of download a file. I just wanna know how to make a "status bar" at terminal on chef recipe. 
Like this

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 14101  100 14101    0     0  13581      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 19694
```

or this

```
9%[=======>                           ]    eta 1m
```

Comment: Can we see the recipe? This seems useless since Chef usually runs as an unattended service.